# I can't import java.servlet in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04

I've add javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar in maven dependencies.

 But I can't import javax.servlet.

 My code

```
     package com.example;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    public class servlet extends HttpServlet{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    
            response.setContentType("text/html");
    
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("./api works. Try ./api/getMessage");
        }
    }
```

in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

error

```
package javax.servlet does not exist
```

Comment: have you updated the pom.xml? in vscode right click to the pom.xml and select update project

Comment: The modified POM file needs to be reprocessed by Maven. VSCode should have a mechanism for invoking that.

Comment: I've updated project but I still can't import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn to `\User folder\.m2\repository`, delete the existed `javax.servlet.jar` in your machine and `Clean java language server workspace` from Command Palette in VS Code.

**Command Palette--> Maven: Add a dependency-->** search with `javax.servlet`, click

```
 javax.servlet-api javax.servlet
```

Reflecting to `pom.xml` is adding the following configuration:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then there'll be notification popping up, click **Now** to download the needed jar.

[image]

This works for my project and no `package javax.servlet does not exist` shows. Please have a try.

Comment: I do it but ... :(. I try echo $CLASSPATH in terminal, and it returns null.Maybe i should try reinstall vscode.

Comment: I think the current project is messed so can you create a new maven project then try again?

Comment: @chungpro. Does it solves your question now?

Comment: Sorry, I still got this error. Extension Langue Support for Java did't add javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar to CLASSPATH when I clicked Now. Can you show me how to fix the setting of this extension?

Comment: @chungpro. Check if you've downloaded the jar successfully in the folder `\User folder\.m2\repository`. or you may try downloading [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.1/javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar) then manually install it in integrated Terminal by command: `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path\to\javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar '-DgroupId=javax.servlet' -DartifactId=javax.servlet-api '-Dversion=4.0.1' -Dpackaging=jar `, after the installation then add the dependency in pom.xml.

Comment: I've downloaded the jar successful. When I complied java, I tried pressed F5 instead of using Run Code Extension. Then it worked. Because of my mistake, I will mark your answer for your conscientious help.

Comment: @chungpro. Glad to know your question has been resolved. Happy Coding:)